Was sind Spitzen oder eine Spitzensammlung
In einem Buch aus dem Jahre 1903 redet eine Frau öfters von "Spitzen" und ihrer "Spitzensammlung". Was sind diese Spitzen?

Did you look up "Spitze" in the dictionary? Which of the meanings given there sound plausible to you for your case?

Also, Old High German was a smidgen earlier, so I'll remove the tag ;)

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitze_(Stoff)

http://das-kloeppelmuseum.de/internationale-spitzensammlung/ + http://das-kloeppelmuseum.de/internationale-spitzensammlung/

Ohne mehr Kontext kann man nur vermuten, worüber die Frau spricht bzw. schreibt, denn das Wort "Spitze" hat mehrere Bedeutungen.
Vermutlich ist von einem (dekorativen) Garngeflecht die Rede. Das Wort "Spitze" leitet sich dabei vom althochdeutschen "spizzi", mittelhochdeutsch "spiz", "spitz(e)", ab, das nach Kluge/Seebold (Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache) zusammen mit "Spieß" zu einer "schwer abgrenzbaren Gruppe auf einer Grundlage "*spei-" gehört. Wikipedia
hat einen Artikel darüber, auf Englisch wird diese Art Stoff als "lace" bezeichnet.
"Spitze" ist der Gattungsbegriff und einzelne Erzeugnisse dieser Stoffart werden im Plural auch zu "Spitzen" dekliniert. Die "Spitzensammlung" wäre dann eine Sammlung von Stücken dieser Machart.
Eine andere mögliche Bedeutung ist: "sarkastische Äußerung, die darauf abzielt, (vermeintliche oder tatsächliche) Fehlhandlungen anderer bloßzustellen". Deine Frage etwa könnte und sollte mehr Kontext enthalten, dann wäre die Beantwortung einfacher. man könnte das aber nicht nur so (neutral) darstellen, sondern zum Beispiel:

Du hast Dir bei Deiner Frage viel Mühe gegeben, auch den letzen Rest an Kontext zu tilgen.

Das wäre eine "Spitze". Es beinhaltet dieselbe Kritik, bringt sie aber auf sarkastische Weise zum Ausdruck.
Daß die literale Bedeutung von "Spitze" (also sich scharf verjüngendes Ende eines Gegenstandes) bekannt ist, davon gehe ich aus.

Nachbemerkung: mittlerweile hat es sich eingebürgert, "spitzen-" als Vorsilbe für heruasragende Exemplare zu verwenden ("Spitzenforschung", "Spitzenleistung", etc.). Diese Verwendung war Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts aber noch nicht üblich, weshalb ich glaube, daß diese Bedeutung hier nicht in Betracht kommt.
